# Can I use Group Policy or another method to determine which Services startup by User or Group?

Tags: windows-7, services, group-policy

We have an application that we use that loads as a service on logon, and I'd like to disable the service from running when an Administrator logs in to their account. I've done some research and haven't figured it out yet. Any ideas? This is in a Windows 7 environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a login script that does if (isAdmin ) { sc service stop }.. That is psuedo code but it should be very easy to work out.

Comment: Might not be easy for everyone. A bit more detail might help, otherwise this may as well have been posted as a comment.

Comment: I tried doing a batch file script with a net stop, but it requires admin rights. I tried putting it in via GPO, but it takes a long time for the service to stop (if it even does) and ends up being faster to just let it load and close the application.